# Problem with this error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

Tags: node.js, reactjs

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

This error keeps coming up and will not let me run my website. Any help or assistance would be great. I just need to figure out what exactly to change in order to get this running.

```
    import React from "react";
    import styled from "styled-components";
    import { AppContext } from "../App/AppProvider";
    import PriceTile from "./PriceTile";

    export default function() {
      return (
        <AppContext.Consumer>
          {({ prices }) => (
            <PriceGrid>
              {prices.map((price, index) => (
                <PriceTile key={`priceTile-${index}`} index={index} price={price} />
              ))}
            </PriceGrid>
          )}
        </AppContext.Consumer>
      );
    }
```

Comment: Please show your `AppContext.Provider`

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are not providing an initial value to your `Context`,

Check in `../App/AppProvider` there is some call to `React.createContext`, check that you provide an object with `prices` that is an empty array.

Comment: Where would i add that tho?

Comment: as i wrote, check `../App/AppProvider` file.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the existence of `prices` before doing the map:

```
<AppContext.Consumer>
  {({ prices }) => (
    <PriceGrid>
      {prices && prices.map((price, index) => (
        <PriceTile key={`priceTile-${index}`} index={index} price={price} />
      ))}
    </PriceGrid>
  )}
</AppContext.Consumer>
```

...or you could default `prices` to an empty array:

```
<AppContext.Consumer>
  {({ prices = [] }) => (
    <PriceGrid>
      {prices.map((price, index) => (
        <PriceTile key={`priceTile-${index}`} index={index} price={price} />
      ))}
    </PriceGrid>
  )}
</AppContext.Consumer>
```

...or, better still, do both:

```
<AppContext.Consumer>
  {({ prices = [] }) => (
    <PriceGrid>
      {prices && prices.map((price, index) => (
        <PriceTile key={`priceTile-${index}`} index={index} price={price} />
      ))}
    </PriceGrid>
  )}
</AppContext.Consumer>
```